# React Native Flexbox stacking view over each other

Tags: reactjs, flexbox, native

How can I stack these 3 boxes one over the other?

I tried setting all of these but did not help
`justifyContent: 'center', alignContent: 'center',alignSelf: 'center'`

Code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, View } from 'react-native';

export default class FlexDirectionBasics extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      // Try setting `flexDirection` to `column`.
      <View style={{  flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row' ,alignItems: 'center' ,
        justifyContent: 'center', alignContent: 'center',alignSelf: 'center'}}>
        <View style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'powderblue'}} />
        <View style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'skyblue'}} />
        <View style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'steelblue'}} />
      </View>
    );
  }
};

// skip this line if using Create React Native App
AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => FlexDirectionBasics);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `right` property to overlap the `View` on another.

```
<View style={{  flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row' ,alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', alignContent: 'center', alignSelf: 'center'}}>
  <View style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'powderblue'}} />
  <View style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'skyblue', right: 20}} />
  <View style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'steelblue', right: 30}} />
</View>
```

[image]
**Note:**
Let me know if you would like to make it in different way.

Comment: Is there a way by which I can make all 3 boxes on top of each other?

Comment: There are one top of another right now. Change width, height, top, bottom, left and right values or views to observe them.

Comment: https://googleweblight.com/i?u=https://unbug.gitbooks.io/react-native-training/content/32_absolute_%26_relative.html&hl=en-IN